# ¿Cómo descargar un archivo excel de MySQL y enviarlo por correo?

Tags: php, mysqli, email, phpexcel

¡Buen día!
Tengo una duda, quiero descargar un archivo excel de MySQL para poder enviarlo vía correo. Pero no estoy muy seguro de qué procedimiento seguir. Este es el código que tengo; al momento de ejecutarlo me aparece el siguiente error: 
**Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: Could not access file: 31-2020-02-06-12-46.XLS**

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require ("Exception.php");
require ("PHPMailer.php");
require ("SMTP.php");
require("/home/includes/config.php");
require("/home/includes/herramientas.php");
$link=new mysqli(BDhost,BDusr,BDpwd,BDnme);
if($link->connect_errno){
die("Fail:(".$link->mysqli_connect_errno().")".$link->mysqli_connect_errno());
}
$link->set_charset("utf8");
$result= "SELECT resultado, archivo FROM bloque WHERE id = 757";
$resultTest = $link->query($result);
if($registroResultados = $resultTest->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
echo $registroResultados['resultado'] . '<br>';
$archivo = $registroResultados['archivo'];
}

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                try {
                    //Server settings
                    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
                    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
                    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
                    $mail->Username   = '';                     // SMTP username
                    $mail->Password   = '';                               // SMTP password
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

                    //Recipients
                    $mail->setFrom('');
                    $mail->addAddress(''); 

                    $mail->AddAttachment($archivo);

                    // Content
                    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
                    $mail->Subject = utf8_decode('Errores');
                    $mail->Body    = $registroResultados['resultado'] . '<br>';

                    //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

                    $mail->send();
                   // echo 'Message has been sent';
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
                }
?>
```

Comment: El error menciona que no encuentra el archivo. No será que está dentro de algun directorio distinto al archivo php?

Comment: Pero... ¿qué hay realmente en tu columna `archivo`? ¿Es una ruta a un XLS, es un BLOB o qué es? Si es una ruta, una vez obtenido el nombre tendrás que obtener el archivo que haya en esa ruta.